# Selenium append list of paragraphs to single variable

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

Good evening everyone,

I am not familiar with webscraping so I thought I would pick up a simple project for myself but I am running into some problems.

A small portion of my html looks like this:

```
<div id="comment-901408_wrap">
    <div class="cPost_contentWrap ipsPad">
        <div data-role="commentContent" class="ipsType_normal ipsType_richText ipsContained" data-controller="core.front.core.lightboxedImages">
            <p>
                Text1
            </p>
            <p>
                Text2
            </p>
            <p>
                Text3
            </p>
            <p>
                Text4
            </p>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There will be multiple comment-[id]_wrap ids, all with 1 or more p elements. What I want to achieve is to make a table that has two columns; comment ID and text. An example would look like this (just the dataframe is fine):

[image: Example Table]

Is this achievable? I could attach some code I have tried but I don't believe that will really lead anywhere

Answer (score 0):

This script will find every `<div>` with `id` in form of pattern `comment-XYZ`, get all text and add it to a DataFrame:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<div id="comment-901408_wrap">
    <div class="cPost_contentWrap ipsPad">
        <div data-role="commentContent" class="ipsType_normal ipsType_richText ipsContained" data-controller="core.front.core.lightboxedImages">
            <p>
                Text1
            </p>
            <p>
                Text2
            </p>
            <p>
                Text3
            </p>
            <p>
                Text4
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

r = re.compile(r'comment-(\d+)')
all_data = []
for div in soup.find_all(id=r):
    all_data.append([r.search(div['id'])[1], div.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')])

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=['Comment ID', 'tekst'])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Comment ID                    tekst
0     901408  Text1 Text2 Text3 Text4
```